# What is the specific key and tuning for this tongue drum I just got?

Tags: notation, scales, tuning, percussion

I just got a tongue drum and I'm not sure how to look up music or tabs specifically for it. The numbers starting at 1 and going around clockwise are: 1, 6 with a dot below, 2, 5, 1 with a dot above, 5 with a dot below, 6, 3.

Please let me know if anyone has any tips to look up music for this drum and whether it is diatonic, pentatonic, or what.